# Criteria to return all records if selection from form is both

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to pass multiple query criteria from form controls. I'm using
the following type of syntax for the criteria.

```
IIf([Forms]![ReportsForm]![cmbLvl]="ALL", "*", [Forms]![ReportsForm]![cmbLvl])
```

It works for the else clause. But it does not work for the `ALL` Scenario. Is there an easy way to make this work.

What I am trying to do is to return all records and not just one type. For example. On a table I want to be able to search for both Male and Female. Not just Male or vice versa. Not just female only too. But both.

I also tried `Like Nz([Forms]![ReportsForm]![cmbLvl],"*")` . That did not work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a parameter to return all records if Null](http://access.mvps.org/access/queries/qry0001.htm) shows how you can use a Null field value to lift that field's filter.
To adapt this, you could use:
`[Forms]![ReportsForm]![cmbLvl]="All" OR [Forms]![ReportsForm]![cmbLvl]`

If you need to show "ALL" as a combobox choice rather than just leaving it blank, consult [Adding "All" to a listbox or combobox](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0043.htm)'s part about creating a union query including a null value listed as "All".